# Diferencias entre "foo instanceof Tipo" y "foo.getClass() == Tipo.class/fuu.getClass()"

Tags: java, clase, comparaciones, tipos

A la hora de determinar si un objeto pertenece a un tipo básicamente se utiliza una de estas dos soluciones:

```
foo instanceof Tipo;
```

O

```
foo.getClass() == Tipo.class;
```

La pregunta es: ¿Qué ventajas y desventajas ofrece cada una y en qué casos es mejor utilizarlas?

> *NOTA: Aunque ponga una respuesta me gustaría saber si está completa, correcta, se puede mejorar o hay algo que se me ha pasado.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### instanceof

Según la [documentación de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

Es decir, `instanceof` devolverá `true` si el objeto de la parte izquierda es una instancia del tipo especificado a la derecha, un subtipo o implementa su interfaz.

#### .getClass() ==

Utiliza el operador `== equal to` para comparar las dos partes devolviendo sólo `true` si son exactamente igual. Esto es que las dos partes tienen que ser exactamente de la misma clase.

#### Diferencias y uso

De lo anterior tenemos que **`instanceof` sirve para conocer si un objeto pertenece a una clase o "sus hijas". Esto incluye a las [clases anónimas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)** y hace que sea muy útil para mantener un código elegante y conciso donde un simple cambio al sobrescribir un método nos daría de otro modo una comparación errónea. El lado negativo es que **no podemos comparar un objeto contra otro, sino que debemos especificar un tipo a su derecha**.

Por otra parte, **`class == class` permite comparar un objeto contra otro o contra una clase y si devuelve `true` sabemos que ambas partes van a comportarse igual** porque son exactamente del mismo tipo.

Además **el operador `==` es transitivo** (se puede leer de izquierda a derecha y al revés con el mismo resultado) **mientras que `instanceof` no lo es** pudiendo evaluarse distinto si "cambiáramos" el sentido de evaluación.

Esto es especialmente importante tenerlo en cuenta cuando se implementen métodos como `equals`, `hashCode` o `compareTo` ya que necesitan ser transitivos o tendríamos un [error de contrato](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) si en ejecución se detectara verdadero que `(A > B & B > C & A <= C)` o `(A.equals(B) != B.equals(A))`. Por lo tanto **en las implementaciones de métodos transitivos NO se debe usar `instanceof`**.

Estos son los casos que se me han ocurrido para ver la diferencia con su salida:

> **Operación class == class**
>   subtipo vs SubClase: (subtipo.getClass() == Hija.class)) es true
>   subtipo vs anónimo: (subtipo.getClass() == anonimo.getClass()) es false
>   anónimo vs subClase: (anonimo.getClass() == TablaNiveles.class) es false
>   anónimo vs SuperClase: (anonimo.getClass() == JTable.class) NO COMPILA  
>   **Operación Objeto instanceof Class**
>   subtipo vs anónimo: (subtipo instanceof anonimo.getClass()) NO COMPILA
>   subtipo vs SubClase: (subtipo instanceof Hija) es true
>   subtipo vs SuperClase: (subtipo instanceof Padre) es true
>   anónimo vs SubClase: (anonimo instanceof Hija) es true
>   anónimo vs SuperClase: (anonimo instanceof Padre) es true