# comprobar que una clase hereda de otra

Tags: java

Tengo un problema comprobando que una clase herede de otra.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Class<Serializable> serializable = (Class<Serializable>) Class.forName("java.io.Serializable");
Class<String> stringClass = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.String");
System.out.println(stringClass.getClass().isAssignableFrom(serializable));
Serializable s = new String();
System.out.println("¿Porqueeeeeeeeee?");
```

Como demuestra la linea 4, string hereda de serializable por lo que espero que isassignablefrom me devuelva true.

No puedo usar `instanceof` por que las clases las obtengo por reflexión, y por tanto lo tengo que comprobar desde el objeto `Class`

Comment: "*tengo un problema*" es muy poco descriptivo. Quizás te ayudaría a obtener mejor ayuda si explicaras qué estás obteniendo y qué hubieses esperado obtener. Para agregar texto, el enlace a [edit] está debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: La clase `String` *no* hereda de la clase `Serializable`, sino que la implementa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber si una clase hereda de otra simplemente usa la palabra clave `instanceof`:

```
objetoAProbar instanceof Clase;
```

Eso te devuelve true si `objetoAProbar` es una instancia de esa clase o si implementa esa interfaz, si es una interfaz lo que pones a la derecha.

Puedes aprender algo más del tema en una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36813/diferencias-entre-foo-instanceof-tipo-y-foo-getclass-tipo-class-fuu-getc) que publiqué hace un tiempo.

#### EDITO

Si no puedes usar `instanceof` puedes usar para tu caso:

```
Class<String> clazz = String.class;
System.out.println(Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz));
```

La salida de este código te dará:

> true